# Dissapearing ImageViews in View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm using Xcode 5.1.1.     I'm creating a game and using 2 view controllers. The main view controller has the game's title, a NEXT button and below the title an image view of a platform that i programmed to moving back and forth. When i tap the segued NEXT it takes me to 2nd view controller which has the game. After you lose in the game, a REPLAY button pops up and a BACK button pops up. You can tap REPLAY button or tap BACK button to go back to main view controller which has the title, floating image view, and NEXT button.

My problem is when i'm tapping on the segued BACK button to go to main view controller the image view starts moving strangely and then disappears off the screen within 5 seconds. How do i stop this from happening?

(Think about games like Swing Copters. When you lose the game you can tap the BACK arrow and it takes you to the intro page and it has a swinging platform and the title moving up and down. My issue is my moving platform is disappearing off the screen. How do i get it to stop doing that?)

Comment: please show your code behind the back button.

Comment: I don't have code behind the back button. I just used the modal Segue from 2nd view controller to main view controller.

Comment: This might not have anything to do with your problem, but you shouldn't go back to the main view controller with a modal segue -- segues (except for unwinds) always instantiate new controllers, so you're not really going back, you're creating a new instance of the main view controller.

Comment: So instead of using Modal i should create a custom button?